# Create a working link on desktop

Tags: launcher, symbolic-link, .desktop

I am totally new to Ubuntu/Linux and I want to create a link on a desktop (is this called an application launcher?).

I created a .desktop file placed on the Desktop with this content but it doesn't start the application:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Comment=GIT Version Control System 6.0.3
Icon=/usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg-64.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Name[en_US]=SmartGIT 603
```

ll outputs...

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 diulrich diulrich  321 Jun 18 18:35 SmartGIT 603.desktop*
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Also, I have checked '*Allow executing file as program*' in the Permissions tab when right-clicking the desktop symbol.

**Update:**
I tried to set  required environment variable *SMARTGITHG_JAVA_HOME* in .bashrc, .profile and in /etc/environment without success.

Modifying the *EXEC* property in the .desktop file this way:

```
Exec=env SMARTGITHG_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40 /usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg.sh
```

I am able to start the application by clicking the desktop symbol.

I wonder why this happens? Is GNOME (GNOME is responsible for running .desktop files, isn't it?) using another shell so that it does not execute .bashrc/.profile an subsequently SMARTGITHG_JAVA_HOME is not set?

Comment: If it is a shell script you might want to check with `Terminal=true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with gnome panel.

If it is not already installed run:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`

Then create the shortcut with:
`gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new`

In the creation window choose the type and location of the target and then click OK.

Comment: I get *E: Command line option --create-new is not understood*

Comment: Just tested it on 12.04 and it works fine for me. Can you post a screenshot of the command you entered and the output you got.

Comment: myName@ub1204d:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
E: Command line option --create-new is not understood
myName@ub1204d:~$

Comment: There are two seperate commands. First run `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` to instal gnome panel then `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new` to create the desktop icon.

Comment: Here's the generated output:
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg-64.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg.sh
Comment[en_US]=SmartGIT 6.0.3 yet
Name[en_US]=SmartGIT 6.0.3
Name=SmartGIT 6.0.3
Comment=SmartGIT 6.0.3 yet
#Icon=gnome-panel-launcher

...but couble-clicking on it has no effect.

Comment: Is it the right exec path? What happens when you start `usr/local/bin/develop/versioncontrol/smartgithg-6_0_3/bin/smartgithg.sh` in a terminal?

Comment: I copied the value from the *Exec* attribute in the desktop file and ran in a shell...and SmartGit started properly.

Comment: See my update in the question above, please.

Comment: When starting from the desktop file no shell is opened so the path from .bashrc aren't set.

Comment: Okay. So, I have to set the env variable as described above or create a .sh file in which I export that env variable and call *smartgithg.sh* afterwards...